# PDF with layers that show/hide specific symbols (fonts)

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, layers

I have a large Indesign document (500+ pages) that has 6 special symbols from a font that appears frequently throughout the text.

My issue is that when finished, I will also need to create a version of the document that replaces this set of symbols with a different font set. Instead of creating two sets of PDFs, I would like to generate a single PDF that allows the two different sets of symbols/fonts to be shown/hidden using layers instead of duplicating the entire text of the pdf on two layers. All 6 symbols may appear, in total, 1000+ times so doing this by hand is out of the question.

Is there a way to seperate the occurances of the locations of these specialty fonts onto their own layers while retaining their relative position to other text?

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that something you have to duplicate.

In this gif there are two layers with the same text content.
The icons are within an **Anchor Object**, all with the same width/height to avoid the text moving.

The top layer text frame has the text color transparent and the anchor objects a paper color fill to hide the bottom icons.

The Anchor objects have an **Object Style** with a linked Paragraph Style with the icons font.

To get two text frames in two layers with different icons, just find/replace one object style for the next in a new empty document. Then copy/paste the resulting text frame to the original file.

[image]